# output(c) for writing a function

Tags: c, function, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

float euro (float usd);

int main (void)
{
    float usd = 1.00;
    do
    {
        printf("How many USD you got?\n");
        usd = get_float();
    }
    while(usd < 0);
    {
    printf("enter something greater than zero please!\n");
    }


}

float euro (float usd)
{

    float d = usd * 0.84;

    return(d);
}
```

this is my code. Im trying to write a function that converts USD to euros and then can recall the function but i got confused and now no matter what every output is "enter something greater than zero please!

Comment: Well, `printf` always runs, if the `while` loop completes.

Comment: BTW where are you calling `euro`?

Comment: forgot to mention, my code is a mess. the printf statement was just one of my problems. now that you point them out to me, i realize how shit this all is lol.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` is not grouped with the `printf` below it, but with the `do` above it.

Let's reformat to make the distinction more clear:

```
do
{
    printf("How many USD you got?\n");
    usd = get_float();
} while(usd < 0);

{
    printf("enter something greater than zero please!\n");
}
```

The `do..while` loop continues until you input a positive value.  After that, you have a block that *always* runs.

You probably want to put an `if` check inside the loop to see if the error message should be printed:

```
do
{
    printf("How many USD you got?\n");
    usd = get_float();
    if (usd < 0) {
        printf("enter something greater than zero please!\n");
    }
} while(usd < 0);
```

Comment: also, after i run this loop i need to have a printf statement that tells the user how many euros they have after entering the positive float of USD. i want to make a function and recall it. if youre willing to help.